# how to pass two javascript arrays to a servlet using json and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, servlets

I want to pass two arrays from javascript to servlet and store them into database. I have tried it using json. Below is my code. I am not understanding how to fetch those arrays in servlet.

When I try to access json object by using request.getParameter() in servlet it gives null pointer Exception.

**Ajaxtrial.jsp**

```
obj=new Object();
obj.lat=lat[0];
obj.lon=lon[0];
document.write( JSON.stringify(obj) );
var jobj=JSON.stringify(obj);

$.ajax({
  url: "ActionServlet",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {point:jobj},
  contentType: 'application/json',
  mimeType: 'application/json',
  success: function (data) {},
  error:function(data,status,er) {
    alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
  }
});
```

**ActionServlet.java**

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
response.setContentType("application/json");
// PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("point"));// gives null pointer exception
try {
  System.out.println(jsonObj.get("lat"));
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what is output of `document.write( JSON.stringify(obj))` in browser?

Comment: this is the output [{"lat":18.765913990627432,"lon":73.4710693359375},{"lat":18.950453518130693,"lon":74.16595458984375},{"lat":18.765913990627432,"lon":74.83062744140625},{"lat":18.336276593834416,"lon":74.94049072265625},{"lat":17.96567026450932,"lon":74.7235107421875}]

Comment: have your problem solved?